# JS / HTML visual calendar

Tags: javascript, html, calendar

I want to create a hotel booking website, to be more precise - nice looking calendar with data from SQL with clickable elements. But now main question is how to create something like on the picture, can you advice a nice framework or any other solution?
[image: Calendar]

Comment: Where does your image come from? Maybe that would be an interesting base to start programming from.

Comment: DHTMLX but.. its not free.